How do I help SBCL find libcrypto (and some other libraries)?
I have just upgraded to SBCL 1.4.3, and I'm having trouble loading foreign libraries while loading my package with Quicklisp. Everything worked before the upgrade.
I get this error:
(CFFI::FL-ERROR "Unable to load any of the alternatives:~%   ~S" ("libcrypto.so.1.1" "libcrypto.so.1.0.0" "libcrypto.so.3" "libcrypto.so"))
   source: (ERROR 'LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR :FORMAT-CONTROL CONTROL
                  :FORMAT-ARGUMENTS ARGUMENTS)

I can verify that I have the requested libraries installed, and my LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains a path to the directory containing the library file. I am using Fedora Linux 38 on a ThinkPad.
Any thoughts?
Thank you!

upgraded to  1.4.3?

See this question from a few days ago and try loading the shared library directly like they attempted. Might be the same situation - 32bit sbcl, only 64bit libraries being looked at.

How embarrassing. I inadvertently downgraded by selecting the latest x86 instead of amd64 binary. Reckon I should delete this question?
